# problems with database after moving live drupal site to local site

Tags: drupal-8

To move my live drupal 8 site to a new local site I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_zss-fPkvqw&list=PLtaXuX0nEZk-ow4oT3yqxmjk4IRHz4jHl) tutorial by OS Training on YouTube. I am aware that they are doing the migration the other way around, but it shouldn't make that big a difference I guess.
They tell you to start by creating your new drupal 8 site and then moving some folders between your old site and the new one. The last step is to import your old database into the database of the new site.

I did all that but when I visit my new local drupal 8 site it first appears  to show nothing until you scroll A LOT and then I'm able to get to things like my content and content types, where I see that nothing has happened. If I go check the database of the new site I see that everything is there that should be there, but I just can't get it to show up on the site itself.

I guess there's something wrong with the connection to the database, but I have no clue how to fix it. Any ideas?

-sidenote: I am using Acquia Dev Desktop to set up my local site

Comment: did you clear registry?
Error log?

Answer (score 0):

Compare the `sites/default/settings.php` file between live and local.

Make sure you have cleared all caches and rebuilt the DB. Also, check for errors using chrome developer console and write them down here.